# force git to open browser for authentication

Tags: git, authentication, ubuntu, git-clone, git-credential-manager

I am trying to clone a repo from Azure DevOps, but the repo URL contains the username found when browsing to the repo page on our DevOps repo page. This is not my username and so when I try to clone, in my Ubuntu VM instance, it asks me for the password - which I don't know.

How can I tell git to ask me for the username and password via browser authentication, like the login seen here?..

[image]

Comment: I would remove the name/username from the screenshot (and that's not an attempt to answer the question).

Comment: And you have tried cloning setting your username (or even, no username) in the URL?

Comment: The screenshot is from the internet. Note the use of 'contoso' example solution name.
Yes, I have tried cloning username etc.
I've realised the solution to my problem, which is essentially that I missed a step in my cloning process (see my answer below.)

Answer (score 0):

Having re-visited the (rather lengthy) steps I was following to perform the setup of my VM instance, I realised that I had missed this:

```
git-credential-manager-core configure
```

Once I executed this, and repeated the following steps, `git clone` opened a browser window and asked me to authenticate.

Decided to leave this here in case it is of use to anyone (perhaps me!) in the future.

Comment: Note that this particular Git credential manager isn't supplied with Git (for various reasons that don't really belong here, I think, but the general idea is that Git doesn't do its own credential stuff: Git hands it all off to other tool-sets, so any time you're fiddling with credentials in Git, check various non-Git things).